# A list(of T) to a Datatable?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Based on other Stackoverflow answers, I've written a simple list and datatable conversion for a test, however in debugging, the Dataset Visualizer doesn't show anything in the datatable. Am I missing something? Here's the code:

```
    Public Class ObjectToTable
    Dim s As List(Of Events)
    Public Sub New(ByVal s As List(Of Events))
        Me.s = s
        s.Add(New Events("A"))
        s.Add(New Events("B"))
        s.Add(New Events("C"))
        s.Add(New Events("D"))
    End Sub
    Public Function GetTable() As DataTable
        Dim props As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(Events))
        For i As Integer = 0 To props.Count - 1
            Dim prop As PropertyDescriptor = props(i)
            myTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType)
        Next
        Dim values As Object() = New Object(props.Count - 1) {}
        For Each Events As Events In s
            For i As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
                values(i) = props(i).GetValue(Events)
            Next
            myTable.Rows.Add(values)
        Next
        Return myTable
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks...

Comment: When/where is `myTable` instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to convert `A list(of T) to a Datatable?`, then the following code may be a better approach.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Reflection

<Extension()> _
Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToDataTable(Of T As Class)(data As List(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim result As New DataTable()
        Dim type As Type = GetType(T)
        Dim list = (From p As PropertyInfo In type.GetProperties() Where (p.CanRead AndAlso (p.GetIndexParameters().Length = 0)) Select New With {.[Property] = p, .Column = New DataColumn(p.Name, p.PropertyType)})
        result.Columns.AddRange((From obj In list Select obj.Column).ToArray())
        If (Not data Is Nothing) Then
            result.BeginLoadData()
            Array.ForEach(Of T)(data.ToArray(), Function(item As T) result.Rows.Add((From obj In list Select obj.[Property].GetValue(item, Nothing)).ToArray()))
            result.EndLoadData()
        End If
        result.AcceptChanges()
        list = Nothing
        type = Nothing
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

**Usage**

```vb
Imports {YOUR.NAMESPACE}.Extensions

Dim list As New List(Of Events)({New Events("A"), New Events("B"), New Events("C"), New Events("D")})
Dim table As DataTable = list.ToDataTable()
```

Comment: Following that, is it possible to use that same "Public Function ToDataTable" to create a datatable for every element of a list (of list)?

Comment: Yes, but it will only create a datatable based on the `List(T)` properties `Capacity` and `Count`. Here's an example using strings: `Dim table As DataTable = New List(Of List(Of String))({New List(Of String)({"a", "b", "c"}), New List(Of String)({"d", "e", "f"})}).ToDataTable()`